# How to remove linux from dual boot with windows?

Tags: kali-linux, windows, dual-boot

I dual booted kali linux with windows pre installed. Now I want to delete kali linux completely. What should I do? I forgot on which partition I installed linux on. On visiting kali linux and seeing its partition size , it says its of 29.4 gb. On seeing if there is any partition of 29.4 gb, in disk management on windows there is none. How could I delete kali linux completely.

Comment: This is a Windows question not Linux.

Comment: In the form this question is asked, you are asking how to do something on Windows so I suggest asking on superuser.com.  I'd remind you to make sure windows boots by default first or you might face a broken boot once you delete Kali.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about maintenance to be performed under windows, and should rather be asked on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0):

Windows will not "see" the Kali partition by default. You would have to go to "Disk Management" and check from there.

Similar question already answered in this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader